# Initialize object property with use other properties of same object

Tags: javascript, object

I am newbie in JS. And my question is: How I can pretty initialize object property with use other properties of same object.

Example:

```
var obj = {
  par1 : 2*2,
  par2 : this.par1
};
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During Object literal declaration you have to use the full reference:

```
var myObject = {
    par1 : 2*2,
    par2 : myObject.par1
};
```

The `this` keyword will only work on an instantiated Object.

Comment: I didn't get your explanation of the `this` keyword, how can this type object be instantiated?

Comment: @Rigotti An Object literal cannot be instantiated.

Answer (score 3):

I am surprised no one mentioned the solution I will provide. @Rigotti and @Jivings are incorrect. You can not reference an object before it is initialized. To have more control over the initialization of an object use a `function` to serve as the constructor of your object. Ex:

```js
var myObject = new function(){
  this.par1 = 2*2
  this.par2 = this.par1
}

console.log(myObject)
```

Answer (score -1):

This way:

```
var obj = {
   par1 : 2*2,
   par2 : obj.par1
};
```